# Evaluate $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} x^x$

Tags: calculus, limits

I know when evaluated it gives one but I can't figure out how to prove it.  Can anyone help?
I believe it requires L'Hopitals rule and taking a natural log but i cannot figure out the exact math.

Comment: Let $y = x^x$, take log of both sides, use power rule for log to get $\log y= x \log x$, take the limit of both sides by using l'hospital's rule. And do the algebra to get 1.

Comment: Also, it's nice to write the whole question in the body of your post, not just in the title.

Answer (score 7):

You are right, you need to take a logarithm. In this case, $$x^x=e^{x\ln x}$$ so the limit can be written as (by continuity of the exponential function) - writing $\exp x$ for $e^x$, $$\exp{\lim_{x\to 0^+}{x\ln x}}=\exp{\lim_{x\to 0^+}{\frac{\ln x}{1/x}}}=\exp \lim_{x\to 0^+}{\frac{1/x}{-1/x^2}}=\exp\lim_{x\to 0^+}{-x}=e^0=1$$ So the limit is $1$. Amazing!

Comment: nice...... (+1)

Comment: But if we approach x from the left, say we take $x=-0.1$ then $x^x=(-0.1)^{-0.1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt[10]{-0.1}}$ which is not defined then how will we know what $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^-} x^x$ will be? Which means that only $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} x^x$ can be evaluated hence $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} x^x$ does not exist.

Comment: Is there something wrong with this reasoning?

Comment: @ShrayanshJyoti You are correct. Notice that I wrote the limits as being one-sided in the post. I wrote $\lim_{x\to 0^+}$ not $\lim_{x\to 0}$.

Comment: @NotNotLogical Ah! Yes. Got it.

Answer (score 1):

The limit is $1$. To see why, let $y = x^x$. then $\ln y = x \ln x = \frac{ \ln x }{\frac{1}{x}} $. Hence

$$ \lim_{x \to 0^+ } \frac{ \ln x }{\frac{1}{x}} =_{L'hop} \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\frac{1}{x} }{ - \frac{1}{x^2}} = \lim_{x \to 0^+ } - x = 0 . $$

Hence,

$$ \lim_{x \to 0^+ } y  = e^0 = 1$$

Answer (score 1):

If you accept that $0^0=1$ , then maybe another approach: since the map $z=f(x,y)=y^x$ is continuous for $y>0$, the limit as $(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)=0^0=1$

Comment: As stated, this is incorrect.  In fact, if we take the limit along the path $x = t$, $y=0$, we get the limit 0.

Comment: Yes, it is a 1-sided limit, $0^x$ , as $x \rightarrow 0^+$. Notice I did state $y>0$.

Comment: Oh, I missed the restriction $y>0$.  I'm sorry: the system won't let me reverse my downvote now.

Comment: << If you accept that $0^0=1$ >> . The snag is that nobody can accept that as a general rule : http://fr.scribd.com/doc/14709220/Zero-puissance-zero-Zero-to-the-Zeroth-Power

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}x^x~=~\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg(\frac1n\bigg)^\frac1n~=~\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{\sqrt[n]n}~.~$ But how much is $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]n$ ? Let us approach $\infty$ on a [logarithmic scale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_scale), and see what happens! $~\sqrt[10]{10}=10^{^\tfrac1{10}},\quad\sqrt[100]{100}=10^{^\tfrac2{10^2}},~\sqrt[1000]{1000}=10^{^\tfrac3{10^3}}$, and generally, $\sqrt[10^k]{10^k}=10^{^\tfrac k{10^k}}.~$ But obviously $\displaystyle\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac k{10^k}=0,~$ so our limit is $10^0=1$, and $\dfrac11=1$. $\big($Of course, instead of $10$ we could have used any other number $>1\big)$. I've decided to post this approach mainly because I find it more intuitive.