# Limit as $x$ goes to $0$ of $x^x$

Tags: calculus, limits

> $$\lim_{x \to 0}x^x$$

I know the answer is one but I have no idea how to get there.  I tried taking a natural log and I think I need lhopitals rule but I keep going In circles.

Comment: You are on the right direction. My recommendation would be to do hopital's rule in the other direction. What I mean by this is if you are considering $f(x)/g(x)$ and using Hopital's rule, try considering instead $(1/g(x))/(1/f(x))$.

Comment: See this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/769644/evaluate-lim-x-rightarrow-0-xx/769646#769646 It's duplicate... and note that the limit should be _one-sided_... the linked question made the same mistake.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\downarrow0}x^x=&\,\lim_{x\downarrow0}\exp(x\log x)=\exp\left(\lim_{x\downarrow0}x\log x\right)=\exp\left(\lim_{x\downarrow0}\frac{\log x}{1/x}\right)=\exp\left(\lim_{x\downarrow0}\frac{1/x}{-1/x^2}\right)\\
&\,=\exp\left(\lim_{x\downarrow0}(-x)\right)=\exp(0)=1.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

Notice $x^x = e^{x \ln x }$ . Why ? Hence,

$$ \lim_{x \to 0^+} x^x = \lim_{x \to 0^+} e^{x \ln x } = \exp( \lim_{x \to 0^+} x \ln x )$$

Now, using Lhopitals rule,

$$ \lim_{x \to 0^+} x \ln x = \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{ \ln x }{ \frac{1}{x}} = \lim_{ x \to 0^+} \frac{ \frac{1}{x}}{- \frac{1}{x^2}} = \lim_{x \to 0^+} -x = 0. $$

Hence, $\lim_{x \to 0^+} x^x = e^0 = 1 $